# How can I implement an AchartEngine line graph with dates on x- axis?

Tags: android

I am implementing a line graph using AchartEngine. I am getting x and y values from webservice. I want to display dates on x-axis and price on y-axis? I am not able to display datwes on x-axis? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AbstractDemoChart class in your achartengine sdk.

```
public LinearLayout execute(Context context, LinearLayout layout,
            String type, List<double[]> x1, List<double[]> values1,
            String maxValue) {
}
```

In this function you can change or edit your x and y axis.